# 500 HTTP ERROR AFTER CHANGING NAMESERVERS (WORDPRESS)

Tags: wordpress, error-handling, server, dns, cloudflare

these are the settings
 wordpress theme: shopkeeper 
plugins: w3 total cache, woo commerce, instagram widget, SEO Yoast, Media file renamed, WP smush, slider revolution , my bag extension, WPBakery Page Builder, WooCommerce Stripe Gateway. I tried even disabling all the plugins 
I don't know about the server environment, I know that is NGINX type.

I have never had any kind of http error 500 problem until today ( 2 months the the website works). Today I asked my hosting provider to change the nameservers as everyone does in order to use the FREE version of cloudFlare, the configuration is active on cloudflare, but the website now is not available (i tried even to reset the .htaccess) nothing changed. I want to use the cloudflare in the way that everyone does but i do not understand why am having this kind of error( is it related to a mistake made by my hosting provider or what?) i did not ask to change anything else but as you can see this is the actual result. So, I don't understand why ( following exactly this steps ) : https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205195708-Step… Thanks for the answer though. Also this is my first time using stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information which is why you're being downvoted. Version of Wordpress, theme and plugins you're running is a good place to start. What kind of server environment (dedicated, VPS, shared) is some more good info. What your configuration was previously helps: Wordpress site on a shared server, using your registrars nameservers, your own private name server, etc.

Here's some general pointers without knowing much more info from you:

If it's a Cloudflare issue, the 500 will return and the page will show "Cloudflare." Your page doesn't, so I'm apt to believe it's a configuration error on your part. This is where knowing what the setup is helps diagnose the problem.

Basic Cloudflare install: You shouldn't have to change your name servers to use Cloudflare if it's simply to have their CDN service. All you do is set it up on the Cloudflare website and then add the CNAME to your DNS record.

Here's the link from CF: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168706-How-do-I-do-CNAME-setup-

> **Step 3:** STOP at Step 4 of the setup, where the website instructions ask you to change your nameservers. **Do not change your
>   nameservers.**

I think you need to contact your registrar again and tell them to point your NS's back to what they were and then read the Cloudflare help very carefully.

Comment: I answered with more details

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions.

- check that nameserver details for your domain do indeed point to Cloudflare
- if you login to your Cloudflare account > DNS you should have an A record that points to your domain's IP and probably a CNAME record for www that is an alias of your domain name

For troubleshooting

- under Cloudflare > Crypto , set SSL to off
- under Cloudflare > DNS, in the status column, take the A record your domain off Cloudflare by clicking to orange cloud. Do the same for your www CNAME
- disable your w3cache plugin on Wordpress.

Good luck!